Filelog receiver to move the offset if log entry exceeded maxSize
I have a use case where I need to use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/filelogreceiver inside opentelemtry collector agent. The requirement is to add a feature to skip log entries if their size increased unreasonably beyond a certain limit.

For instance, given:
(A) log file myservice.log
(B) Three timestamps t0, t1, and t2.

T0: 6Kb of logs
T1: 1GB of logs
T2: 8Kb of logs

The filelog receiver due to entry at T1 will lag behind, as it needs to emit all the logs entries received at T1. I want to skip T1's data and move the reader offset to EOF so at T2 it emits directly T2 data.

This can be achieved by moving the offset of the stanza fileconsumer reader. I created this GitHub PR: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pull/33806. Which offers a mechanism to move the offset if the log entries exceeded the maxSurgeSize. Sadly and reasonably enough, the PR won't be accepted.
I saw that max_log_size is configurable but max_log_size will truncate entries for the scanner, the scanner will end up reading them nevertheless. And we will end up lagging behind in terms of logs being read.
Are there any workarounds you propose?
Thanks!
